# Google Directory API/client lib custom schemas incomplete response

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-directory-api, google-admin-sdk

For few last days I'm facing API and client lib issue while listing custom schemas from directory.

According to doc, response should contain **kind**, **etag** and list of **schemas**, but when called using (Java) client lib or online API explorer

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/schemas/list#response_1

where customer with provided **customerId** does not have any custom schemas in his google admin directory, such response only contains **kind** and **etag** properties and **schemas** is not even present (not empty list, not null, no nothing - forcing **schemas** in request's field parameter does not work either)

```
{
 "kind": "admin#directory#schemas",
 "etag": "\"enlFCt4L0-k8PoIKzRNl5h_fsrc/vyGp6PvFo4Rv1gHuoIWeCReyIC8\""
}
```

which causes (Java) client lib (schemas().list().execute()) to fail on Preconditions check with "**IllegalArgumentException: no JSON input found**" for **schemas** field. For customer with some custom schemas, response is ok with filled "**schemas**" list property.

I think, this (missing schemas response property) behaviour changed few days ago and my question is if someone is facing the same issue or am I having some bad view on it?

Comment: Maybe you need to change the you handle the response? Can you provide the code so it can be reproduced in order to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reported to Google issues, now fixed. No code or lib changes are needed.